# Jenkins npm install didn't work, SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Anybody give me some tips? I'm stuck and I can't solve it

1. I try to connnet my remote server, absolutely Success
2. I use windows batch command

npm -v
npm install
npm run build

3. when i finish my Build Steps, i'll send  build artifacts over SSH

Ok, I guess the problem is that npm install didn't work, because npm install has no logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wYB.png)

Someone give me some hints, I'm a front end developer and not very familiar with these commands

Just npm install success！
npm run build success！

SSH: Transferred 0 file(s), I don't want to see 0 files Transferred!
Just n files Transferred

Comment: npm -v && npm install && npm run build - It works